# Django Test - How to run tests with different settings file for a specific app?

Tags: django, testing, django-testing, django-tests

I have a project and into this project I have different apps.. The problem is, a specific app is another website inside the same project and uses different settings file.

When I run the tests separated, it works perfectly, when I try to run all tests together, the app which uses a different settings file fails..

Any idea how to fix it?

I tried to override the settings into setUp method as below:

```
for s in dir(settings_appA):
    if getattr(settings, s) == None:
        setattr(settings, s, getattr(settings_appA, s))
```

When I do it, works for the specific website but not for other apps..

Any idea?

Comment: The problem is - you are mixing projects and apps. Settings file belongs to a project, applications only define custom settings keys in the project-specific settings. This is how it should be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
./manage.py test <app1> --settings=settings1
./manage.py test <app2> --settings=settings2
```

Comment: Hey @trinchet , thank you for the answer.. As I said before, when I run separated like you proposed, it works. The problem is that I have to run everything together .. I have more than 200 tests...

Comment: Ohh... I see, why you need to use different settings? maybe you just need to use different DBs, urls, etc... if so, you can code you own DjangoTestSuiteRunner https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/testing/advanced/